# Understanding the proof of a criterion of equivalent group extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I stuck in a step of the proof of the equivalence of two group extensions for 30 mins. In the place of red arrow, how does the previous line deduce the next?

PS: The author denote the operation in $G,~G'$ as $+$ for convenience (even outside the abelian group $K$).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you have a group extension means that if $g\in G'$ and $k\in K$ then inside $G'$ you have 
$$g+k=p'(g)k + g.$$

So if $g=l'(x)$, you get 
$$l'(x)+k=xk + l'(x).$$

Apply this to $k=b+h(y)$.