# Stuck in a step of the deduction of cocycle identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-cohomology

In the proof of the cocycle identity, how does the red arrow valid? I'd thought about it for a long while, but can't see the reason.

PS: The author denote the operation in $G$ as $+$ for convenience (even outside the abelian group $K$).

[image]

Comment: (deleting a careless earlier comment that assumed the last three equations are taking place in an abelian group -- in my defense, it's written additively !)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This book appears to be using additive notation for a non-abelian group, where multiplicative notation might be less confusing. The point is that the action of $Q$ on $K$ is given by conjugation in $G$ (this is what the author means when the author says that the extension is "realizing the operators").

It follows that $xf(y,z)$, being $x$ acting on something in $K$, is 
$$
-\ell(x) + f(y, z) + \ell(x).
$$
From here you can get line 2 out of line 1.

Comment: Gosh, I see! Thanks! (PS: Should it be $\ell(x) + f(y, z) - \ell(x)$ right?)

Comment: By the way, can you also help me on a seemingly more difficult deduction [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201997/understanding-the-proof-of-a-criterion-of-equivalent-group-extensions)? :)

Comment: @Eric you're right about the signs, sorry! It's whatever makes the formula work :)